# Validation Rule with $RecordTypeId

Tags: validation

I need to write a validation rule based on the recordTypeId.
I would like to make sure that when the users selects a record via a lookup field the rule will check if the record chosen is of a specific RecordType.

How can I use the $RecordTypeId or $RecordTypeName in the validation rule formula to achieve this?

Comment: Using Record Type Id will be hardcoding and depending on recordtype Ids will change and so putting in custom label and updating it will help....

Comment: If too complex go for a trigger .Using before Trigger will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We started the practice of putting a custom field on any object that we would use a record type for called "Record Type Name".

It's a formula field that has value $RecordType.Name

This lets you refer to record types by name in Apex without having to do an extra query, but it may also keep things simpler for validation rules.

Answer (score 4):

Under Validation Rules you just setup a simple comparison to the Record Type name. An example using Leads would be:

```
RecordTypeId = 'Record Type Name'
```

For a custom object it might be something like:

```
$RecordType.DeveloperName = "Record Type name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Use a filtered lookup if there are additional criteria on the (base) record that you would like to base the validation on.
2. Use the record type name/Id of the record being looked up (using relationships like Customer__r.RecordTypeId)

Comment: Initially I wanted to use a filter on the lookup but my looked up Object is Contract and for some reason a filter cannot be created on Contracts